# When is the Second Coming?

Tags: contradiction, eschatology

When will the Second Coming occur? In Matthew, Jesus seems to allude that the Second Coming will occur within his generation.

> Truly, I say to you, **this generation** will not pass away till all these things take place.
> Matthew 24:34 (RSV-2CE)

And in Mark, it is made more explicit.

> And he said to them, "Truly, I say to you, there are some standing here who will not taste death before they see the kingdom of God come with power."
> Mark 9:1 (RSV-2CE)

However, in the later part of Matthew, Jesus said that the time of the Second Coming is unknown.

> But of that day and hour no one knows, not even the angels of heaven, nor the Son, but the Father only.
> Matthew 24:36 (RSV-2CE)

There is also the same contradiction in the letters of St.Paul. In 1 John, St.Paul said:

> Children, it is the **last hour**, and as you have heard that antichrist is coming, so now many antichrists have come; therefore we know that it is the **last hour**.
>   1 John 2:18 (RSV-2CE)

But in 1 Thessalonians:

> For you yourselves know well that the day of the Lord will come like a **thief in the night**.
>   1 Thessalonians 5:2 (RSV-2CE)

So, did Jesus and St.Paul expect the Second Coming to occur within their generation or not?

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange -- we're different from a forum, so do take [the site tour](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already. Please also see [what we’re looking for in questions](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Your title question doesn't have an answer; the later question ("So, did Jesus and St.Paul expect the Second Coming to occur within their generation or not?") has been answered before -- see e.g. the top two questions linked under "Related" in the right sidebar. You seem also to be wondering what is meant by "the last days" more generally. I don't think the way you have posed your question is a good fit for the Stack Exchange Q&A model. [Could you edit](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/posts/26186/edit) to narrow the scope and focus of your question? Otherwise, it might be closed.